# Is coproduct the same as sum types?

Tags: haskell, type-theory

I was watching [this lecture from Bartosz Milewski](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LkIRsNj9T-8&index=4&list=PLbgaMIhjbmEnaH_LTkxLI7FMa2HsnawM_#t=1635.142339) and he was explaining coproduct and sum types.

On the lecture, He went from one to the other.

Is the coproduct the same as the sum type?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Basically, yes. Coproducts are in principle more general, but that needn't 
necessarily concern you as far as Haskell is concerned.

An example of a category where the coproduct is not a sum type<sup>†</sup> is the [category of vector spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_modules) with linear mappings as the arrows. In this category, disjoint-sum types don't make a lot of sense because they would give you two different zero-vector elements.

Instead, it turns out that *product* types (which in linear algebra are called [direct sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum), but implementation-wise they're tuples, not alternatives) are a coproduct on this category:

```
type LFun v w = v -> w

initial :: VectorSpace w => LFun () w
initial () = zeroV

(+++) :: VectorSpace w => LFun u w -> LFun v w -> LFun (u,v) w
(f+++g) (u,v) = f u ^+^ g v
```

<del>(The standard product on this category is then the [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product). Though it's possible to ignore this and use ordinary tuples as the product type, i.e. the actual coproducts. I think this has to do with the fact that any Hilbert space is isomorphic to its dual space. In my [`constrained-categories`/`linearmap-category`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linearmap-category-0.3.2.0/docs/Math-LinearMap-Category.html) library, the products are tuples, whereas Mike Izbicki [has not done this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/subhask-0.1.1.0/docs/SubHask-Algebra-Vector.html) in the topically similar `SubHask` library.)</del><sub>See Derek Elkins' comment.</sub>

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>I understand “sum type” in the data sense, i.e. as an algebraic data type with structure of a tagged union.</sub>

Comment: Perhaps poser would be a easier and more interesting example.

Comment: [Posets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#In_category_theory) you mean, I take it? They're _easier_, arguably, much _less_ interesting. But if you add them as an extra example, certainly couldn't cause any harm.

Comment: Yes (sorry stupid typo). More interesting because sums and products there have nothing to do with set-theoretical sums and products. In vector spaces you still kinda have set-theoretical sums and products (over sets of indices, when you fix a base for each space). This is my possibly incorrect understanding anyway.

Comment: Ah, that's what you mean. Yes, _sets of indices_ are a possible interpretation that matches the _sum_ and _product_ notion, though I'm personally not a fan of this interpretation because in general, a vector space doesn't have a canonical basis.

Comment: Categorically, there is no definition of "sum type" except for coproduct, so the statement like "the coproduct is not a sum type" is a bit nonsensical. I think what you are effectively trying to say is that the *underlying set* of the coproduct is not the disjoint union of the underlying set of the summands. Also, the category of vector spaces does have categorical products. They happen to coincide with coproducts in the finite case (and this is called a biproduct). They diverge when you consider co/products indexed by infinite sets. Tensor products are something else entirely, categorically.

Comment: @DerekElkins I understand “sum type” as nothing category-theoretical, but just as an algebraic datatype with tagged-union structure. — It's good to hear that the product in **Vectk** is _not_ the tensor product, it was ever nagging a bit on me that I'd just used tuples as the product in my library and implemented tensors separately...